# HTTP Status 500 - No action instance for path /adduser could be created in struts

Tags: java, struts

I have a JSP page in which there is a hyperlink to add a user.

```
<html:link action="openadduser.do"> Add New User < /html:link>
```

My struts-config file contains

```
<action-mappings>
        <action path="/login" name="LoginForm" validate="true" input="/index.jsp"
            type="useraction.LoginAction">
            <forward name="successadmin" path="/home.jsp" />
            <forward name="failure" path="/index.jsp" />
            <forward name="successuser" path="/welcome.jsp" />
        </action>

    <action path="/adduser" name="AdduserForm" validate="true" input="/adduser.jsp"
            type="useraction.AdduserActions">
            <forward name="success" path="/userconfirm.jsp" />
        </action>

       <action path="/openadduser" name="AdduserForm" validate="true" type="useraction.AdduserAction"
            input="/adduser.jsp">
            <forward name="success" path="/userconfirm.jsp" />
        </action>
</action-mappings>
```

And my **adduser.jsp** contains code

```
<html:form action="/adduser">
     < h1 align="center">  ADD NEW USER < /h1>
     < bean:message key="label.fname"/> <br/>
     <html:text property="fname"></html:text><br/>
     <html:errors property="fname" /><br/>
     </html:select>
    <html:submit/>
</html:form></body></html>
```

**AdduserAction.java contains**

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception 
    {
        AdduserForm adduserForm = (AdduserForm) form;

        fname = adduserForm.getFname().toString();
        System.out.println(fname);
        return mapping.findForward("success");

    }
```

I am using a Tomcat server. After I click on the submit button to add a user, 
it gives the following error.
**HTTP Status 500 - No action instance for path /adduser could be created in struts.**

I think there is a problem in the struts-config file.
What can I do to remove this error?
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think appending .do in your jsp should solve the problem

```
<html:form action="adduser.do">
```

Comment: @vicky try removing the "/" from jsp, that is try action="adduser.do"

Comment: It is still giving same error. Actually in struts-config file i have a separate action for submit button on add user and separate action for the hyperlink to open add user jsp . Is there is some conflict in this?

Comment: SEVERE: No action instance for path /adduser could be created
java.lang.ClassCastException: useraction.AdduserActions cannot be cast to org.apache.struts.action.Action

Comment: The action class is not in the classpath or you must have miss spelt the action class!!!

Comment: Pardeep is right, this might be the reason. By the way is it AdduserAction or AdduserActions because you are using oth, or are they really different classes.

Comment: They are different classes. But content is same. Actually i was just trying if it could work. But it is not working.Both have same content.

Comment: I have added AdduserAction class in my question.

Comment: does AdduserAction extends Action class?

Comment: Yes,It is extending Action class.

Comment: @Zohaib actually when you asked whether  AdduserAction extends Action class? Then only i extend it. But it again was showing error. But when i put "/" in adduser.jsp for "/adduser.do" . It started working.      Thank you so much.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer when it's followed by a discussion about it not working?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot extend the 'Action' class in your `LoginAction`. That's the only reason for `no action instance for path`. You must extend the `Action` class, don't forget...

Comment: I don't understand. This seems contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

@vicky : in action tag change `validate="true"` to `validate="false"`

It worked for me...